# Xamarin builds failed with Xcode 8

Tags: ios, build, xamarin.ios, xcode8

I got the this error when rebuild Xamarin iOS after updating UI using Xcode 8:
`Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: Error: Error executing task DetectSdkLocations`

I'm using Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)

Xamarin 6.1 build 5441,
Xamarin.iOS,
Version: 10.0.0.6 (Xamarin Studio Community),
Hash: 6c3fee4,
Branch: xcode8,
Build date: 2016-09-09 13:01:32-0400

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution by Opening Preferences and choose right SDK Location (Xcode.app).
[image]

Restart Xamarin Studio to take effect.

Hope this help anyone has this issue.